# xpages dijit.form.checkbox multiple values

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Using xpages on domino 8.5.3 server.
Can a djcheckbox be use with muiltiple value field similar to a checkboxgroup ?
if so, would it be possible to supply a code snippet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[dijit.form.CheckBox](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/CheckBox.html) can deal with only **one** value and that's true for djCheckBox too as it's based on dijit.form.CheckBox.

You could combine several djCheckBox controls and let it look like a checkBoxGroup. Bind every djCheckBox to a viewScope variable initialized by a document item and write values back at document save.

Here is an example for UI similarity to checkBoxGroup:

```xml
<fieldset
    class="xspCheckBox">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xe:djCheckBox
                        label="abcdefg"
                        id="djCheckBox4"
                        value="#{viewScope.abcdefg}">
                    </xe:djCheckBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xe:djCheckBox
                        label="hijklmno"
                        id="djCheckBox5"
                        value="#{viewScope.hijklmno}">
                    </xe:djCheckBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xe:djCheckBox
                        label="pqrstuvwxyz"
                        id="djCheckBox6"
                        value="#{viewScope.pqrstuvwxyz}">
                    </xe:djCheckBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

I am not sure though what's the reason for your question and if it's worth the extra effort.

Comment: Primarily it because I couldn't get the native xpage checkboxgroup attribute "show disabled control" to work.  And since I had used dojo radio button with that attribute,  i was looking for a consistent look on the page.